# Concatenate zero matrices and sparse matrices in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I achieve the following MATLAB command in Python using `scipy`'s sparse matrices?

```
B=[zeros(numrowsA), A; A', zeros(numcolumnsA)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For horizontal and vertical concatenations in numpy/scipy, use `hstack` and `vstack`.

```
m,n = A.shape
B = sparse.vstack(( sparse.hstack(( sparse.coo_matrix((m,m)), A )), 
                    sparse.hstack(( A.T, sparse.coo_matrix((n,n)) )) ))
```

This is not really specific to sparse matrices, the same is done with `numpy.hstack` and `numpy.vstack` for dense matrices.

Comment: See also [scipy.sparse.bmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bmat.html)